# Is there any way to find the ip address of all users in my LAN network?

Tags: security, networking, ip, lan, ethernet

Imagine that I am working in a corporate network in which all the computers are interconnected using private IPs. Is there any way to find the IP address of different users along with the username without contacting the sysadmin?

Answer (score 0):

Use a scanner like nmap, this will get you all the IPs in your subnetwork.

As for the usernames.. not sure what usernames you're talking about, i think nmap can also give the hostname.

Comment: replace [network] with your actual network, i.e. 192.168.0.0/24

Answer (score 0):

yes you can. if you are interested in IP and Hostname then angryscanner is more than enough

you can download it free and install it without admin privileges. however, if you want to get the usernames then it depends on the network. you need to clarify what usernames you are looking for ? the currently logged on? is your network workgroup ? or domain-based ?

for current logged on users

```
@echo off
for /f %%a in (pcList.txt) do (
echo ********************
echo Host: %%a
echo ********************
For /F "Tokens=2* Delims==\" %%i In (
'WMIC /Node:%%a ComputerSystem GET UserName /Value^|Find "="'
) Do Echo Current Logged in User ID for %%a is: %%j
)
echo ********************
echo Sweep is Complete
echo ********************
pause
```

this is a bat script (copy and paste in text file and rename to anything.bat)

now in the same folder  you need to create a text file (pclist.txt) with all computers or IP addresses

for me I think using IP is very fast

get your network ip and subnet to discover the range of you local network 
generate a list of all possible ips and copy-paste them to the text file

Comment: Thank you taking the effort. But I am using the Ubuntu. It will be helpful if you can get me the corresponding bash program.